# Convert string into this format date - Day Name, month/dayNumber, hour pm or am

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
2020-11-20T14:00:00
```

How can i convert into

```
Friday, 11/20, 2:00 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the date format you wanted.

```js
var param = { weekday: 'long', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true };
var date_today = new Date();

console.log(date_today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", param));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `moment.js` to format the date time. Please check the example below:

```js
var currentDate = "2020-11-20T14:00:00"
var formattedDate = moment(currentDate, "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss").format("dddd, MM/DD, hh:mm A")
console.log(formattedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```